# Firefox extension for saving pinned tabs

Tags: firefox

Firefox enables opening specific sites on start-up. I'm looking for same functionality, but instead of regular tabs, i want them as pinned tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is built-in.

When you pin a tab (<kbd>Right-click</kbd> on a tab → <kbd>Pin Tab</kbd>), this tab will open automatically when you start Firefox.

Documentation: [Pinned Tabs - keep favorite websites open and just a click away](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open)

Comment: Unfortunately in Firefox *Quantum* `60.1.0` and above, the pinned tabs are not bookmarked. Even with a bookmark extension, when bookmarking/saving "all tabs", the pinned ones are left out. AFAICT there is no current workaround, except unpinning all the tabs, and then saving.

Comment: @not2qubit: On my Firefox 62 pinned tabs open automatically after restarting. The question is not about bookmarks.

Comment: Yep, I then realized. Thank for converting to comment.

Comment: Firefox does launch with the pinned tabs most of the time, but it's buggy in my experience. Sometimes it doesn't launch with the pinned tabs, and sometimes it launches with the pinned tabs but doesn't load the corresponding pages in the tabs.